# Firestore in Javascript (React Native) How to get document path with field value

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

So basically:

```
const screamDocument = db.doc(`/screams/${req.params.screamId}`)
```

This line of code works because req.params.screamId is document ID. I just want to know how to write this line but getting document path with FIELD VALUE and not document ID. For example I want a document that inside collection scream but exactly one document which has field value "age" equal to 120. I know how I wqould do that the long way, with querysnapshot and doc.data bla bla but how to write it short and in one line like above but with field value?

like something like this:

```
const postDocument2 = db.collection("posts").where("id", "==", id);
```

but this lacks .doc and doesnt return to me what i want how to add .doc to that line?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it myself, the solution is this: document path ONLY works if you include document ID and not a field called id, so for example this like

```
const screamDocument = db.doc(`/screams/${req.params.screamId}`)
```

is a document path because screamId is document ID of one of documents inside collection screams. If I want to have this document path with some field value, I must store document ID in a sepparate variable and then add it like this:

```
const screamDocument = db.doc(`/screams/${documentId}`)
```

now how to get documentId i mean id of a document thats easy to find snapshot.foreach(doc)
and u can get doc.id its in documentation.